# CURLE_BAD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT happened while using curl_easy_getinfo to retrieve http version info

Tags: c, linux, libcurl

I am writing a downloader for crawler with `libcurl` in linux c. But I am stuck on a curl error.

```
long http_version_code; // http version
test_rc = curl_easy_getinfo(easy_handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_VERSION, &http_version_code);
hd_easy_check_curl_code(test_rc);
```

The `test_rc` is `CURLE_BAD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT`.

Libcurl document says:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <curl/curl.h>
>
> CURLcode curl_easy_getinfo(CURL *handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_VERSION, long *p);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> Pass a pointer to a long to receive the version used in the last http
>   connection. The returned value will be CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0,
>   CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, or CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0, or 0 if the version
>   can't be determined.
>
> ---

Curl ErrorCode:

> CURLE_BAD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT (43)
>
> Internal error. A function was called with a bad parameter.

I have followed the document, any suggestions?

And my libcurl version is `curl-7.50.3`

Comment: Maybe handle  var is not correct

Comment: @LPs this handle var works just fine for other OPTIONS other than CURLINFO_HTTP_VERSION

Comment: Please show a minimal example that reproduces the error.

Comment: @2501 My project is a little large,but I reproduce this with the example in [https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/evhiperfifo.html](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/evhiperfifo.html), add `curl_easy_getinfo()` for `CURLINFO_HTTP_VERSION` in function `check_multi_info()`,run the sample program,this issue will occur.

Comment: I read the code. I cannot see any code path where `curl_easy_getinfo` returns this...